# Using class instance as a function argument

Tags: python, function, class, arguments

Suppose I have something like:

```
class Dog:
   name = ""
   weight = 0
   def __init__(self,name,wg):
       self.name = name
       self.wg = wg

def feed(pet):
   pet.weight = pet.weight + 5
   if pet.weight > 20:
       print("your dog would get too fat")
   else:
       print("it is safe to feed your dog")

my_dog = Dog("sparky",10)
feed(my_dog)
```

Is there anyway to have it so that the changes to pet.weight are not transferred to my_dog.weight?

I want the function to be able to take information from a class instance, perform calculations, and then leave the original instance unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You are reassigning the value of the `pet.weight` attribute on this line:

```
pet.weight = pet.weight + 5
```

Doing this affects the `pet` instance even after the code has returned from the `feed` function.

To fix the problem, simply create a local name that is equal to `pet.weight + 5` and work with that instead:

```
def feed(pet):
   weight = pet.weight + 5
   if weight > 20:
       print("your dog would get too fat")
   else:
       print("it is safe to feed your dog")
```

Now, we use the value of `pet.weight` but avoid changing it.

---

Also, you have defined your class incorrectly.  By doing this:

```
class Dog:
   name = ""
   weight = 0
```

you have made `name` and `weight` to be *class attributes* of `Dog`.  This means that their values will be shared among all instances of `Dog` and modifying them will affect all instances.  In other words, all of your `Dog`s will have the same name and weight.

But then you do:

```
def __init__(self,name,wg):
    self.name = name
```

which overshadows the class attribute `name` with an *instance attribute* of the same name.  Unlike class attributes, instance attributes are unique to each instance of a class.  So, `weight` is still a class attribute (shared by all `Dog`s) while `name` is now an instance attribute (unique to each `Dog`).

I think it would be best if you removed those lines and wrote the `Dog` class like so:

```
class Dog:
   def __init__(self, name, weight):
       self.name = name
       self.weight = weight
```

Now, `name` and `weight` are both instance attributes. Each `Dog` has a unique name and weight and changing either of those values on one `Dog` will no longer affect the other `Dog`s.

For more information on this, you can check out these sources:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Comment: In fact, his attributes will not be shared in practice, because he assigns them in `__init__`.  This will create instance attributes that hide the class attributes. However, you're right that it's better to remove the class attributes, since it can lead to confusing attribute-sharing behavior if the instance attribute is deleted (or if a mutable class attribute is mutated instead of reassigned).

Comment: Right, I have clarified.  I think the OP may have thought that he needed to pre-assign the `name` and `weight` attributes before assigning them in `__init__`.